# Hi! My <h1></h1> tag is not appearing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in codeine.io. I have moved the `<h1>` tag to the body section and then it appears but I want it  in a div so I can center it to the middle of the page. What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4880cded54.js"></script>
<header>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel=”stylesheet” id=”font-awesome-css” href=”//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css” type=”text/css” media=”screen”>
</header>
<script src=”//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js”></script>
  <a href="#" class="back_down" style="display: inline;">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</body>
<div>
  <ul class = "nav nav-pills">
    <li class = "pull-right">
      <a href ="#"> About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class ="pull-right">
      <a href ="#"> Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "pull-right">
      <a href ="#"> Get In Touch</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class = "pageOne">
    <div class="block text-center">
      <h1>Birth of A Method</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class ="btnList">
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Twitter</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Github</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have a the close body element `</body>` midway through your code.

Comment: If it's not in the `<body>` it won't be seen.

Comment: Don't forget the doctype!

Comment: https://www.onlinewebcheck.com/

Answer (score 4):

Please research proper html structure.

Should be:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--All of your links and styles-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--All of your content-->
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html code in invalid. Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4880cded54.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel=”stylesheet” id=”font-awesome-css” href=”//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css” type=”text/css” media=”screen”>
        <script src=”//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js”></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a href="#" class="back_down" style="display: inline;">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>

    <div>
      <ul class = "nav nav-pills">
        <li class = "pull-right">
          <a href ="#"> About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li class ="pull-right">
          <a href ="#"> Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "pull-right">
          <a href ="#"> Get In Touch</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class = "pageOne">
        <div class="block text-center">
          <h1>Birth of A Method</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class ="btnList">
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Twitter</a>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Github</a>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Facebook</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You end your body  before you even put anything in it.

Also you put your header inside of your body...

Try this structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

All of your inputs and meta information will go between the header tags, and everything else should go between the body tags. You won't really need to worry about html for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple: move all your main HTML inside the `body` tag. And you also used `header` instead of `head` tag for your links. Your code should looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel=”stylesheet” id=”font-awesome-css” href=”//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css” type=”text/css” media=”screen”>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <ul class = "nav nav-pills">
        <li class = "pull-right">
          <a href ="#"> About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li class ="pull-right">
          <a href ="#"> Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "pull-right">
          <a href ="#"> Get In Touch</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class = "pageOne">
        <div class="block text-center">
          <h1>Birth of A Method</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="btnList">
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Twitter</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Github</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Facebook</a>
    </div>

    <script src=”//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js”></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4880cded54.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Cheers**